# Парсинг женских имен в датасете "Titanic"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
data['col1'] = data['Name'].str.split(',').str.get(0)
data['col1'].groupby(data['col1']).value_counts()
```

Есть таблица, в которой нужно выбрать самое популярное женское имя (*first name*).
Разделение на имя и фамилию есть, также есть и группировка имён. В таблице около 1000 строк.

Как можно сделать фильтр по полу и как вывести имя, которое повторяется больше всего раз?

[таблица train.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)

Comment: Для того, чтобы посмотреть ваш csv, нужно зарегистрироваться на стороннем ресурсе. Спасибо, нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задача не совсем тривиальная, как может показаться на первый взгляд. Вот пример женских имен из датасета "Titanic":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что у замужних женщин чаще всего после `"Mrs."` стоит имя мужа, а имя и фамилия женщины располагаются в скобках.

Предлагаю сначала парсить имена замужних женщин из скобок, а потом все оставшиеся:

```
def parse_first_name_female(name):
    first = name.str.extract(r"Mrs\.\s+[^(]*\((\w+)", expand=False)
    first.loc[first.isna()] = name.str.extract(r"\.\s+(\w+)", expand=False)
    return first
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]